# list of prime numbers between 1 and 100

Tags: c++

I want to find the list of prime numbers, I try this code but it doesn't show me anything:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int n, i;
    std::cout << "Liste des nombres premiers : " << std::endl;

    for (n = 1; n < 100; n++) {

        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {

            if (n % i == 0)
                std::cout << n << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile; after fix (remove "," in the line "int n,i, ;") it produces some output

Comment: You've a syntactic errors in your code.

Comment: i edit the error

Comment: you should also add "}" in the last line...
ok...but what is your question?

Comment: but the resut it false

Comment: i want to show prime numbers

Comment: your code runs for me and prints lots of numbers (none of them are prime though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To correct program errors:**

1. Initialize the value of `n` as `2`.
2. And print when `i` is equal to `n` not when `n % i` is `0`. It should be rather `n % i == 0` then break.
3. Change `i < n` to `i <= n`.

---

**Try the first approach (used `sqrt()`):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i == 2 || i == 3) { // if number is 2 or 3, then prints it
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) break;
            else if (j + 1 > sqrt(i)) std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Alternative approach:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    for (int n = 2; n < 100; n++)
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            if (i == n) std::cout << i << ' ';
            else if (n % i == 0) break;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but this is not an efficient approach, you can iterate only to square root of (i)

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for letting me know, I was actually changing the variable names according to the original program written by OP.

Comment: @andrzejdoro I've changed the old code to an alternative and the `sqrt` approach as the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like your code at all. Try to do this: create a function that tells you if a number is prime, and then go with a for loop through all numbers from 1 to 100, and check with the function if they are prime.
Here is an easy to remember function (for natural numbers):

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
   if (n <= 1)
      return 0;
   if (n == 2)
      return 1;
   if (n%2 == 0)
      return 0;

   for (int i=3; i*i <= n; i+=2)
      if (n%i == 0)
         return 0;
   return 1;
}
```

This function returns 1 if the number is prime, and returns 0 if it isn't.
The idea is this:

If n is 0 or 1, it is not prime.

If n is 2, it is prime.

If n is a multiple of 2, but it isn't 2, it is not prime.

Then, you have to check if n has any divisors until you get to square root of n (i * i <= n)